# Web project failed to deploy to Bluemix Cloud Foundry Server

Tags: ibm-cloud-tools

Neither by drag-and-drop nor by Add-and-Remove does a dyanamic web project deploy to Bluemix cloud foundry server. Eclipse detected an error and generated online report. Copy of the same is attached.Eclipse has recommended it be discussed here since it is not eclipse but IBM tool. Any help?

[online eclipse error report](http://pastebin.com/GdMNK1xq)

[tutorial being followed](http://www.eclipse.org/cft/documentation/projectPageLink/CFTProjectPagedocumentation.html)

Comment: Add the error output and a better description, not only the link

Answer (score 0):

The tutorial link is coming from the Eclipse CFT open source project. When you are working with the Bluemix, it is strongly recommended to use the IBM Eclipse Tools for Bluemix (ETB) instead. ETB is built on top of the CFT project so it supports all functions provided by CFT but it also has the Bluemix specific server type that you can use. It is tailored for Bluemix with extra functions like package server support and EAR publishing support.

You can follow this [installation instruction](https://developer.ibm.com/wasdev/downloads/#asset/tools-IBM_Eclipse_Tools_for_Bluemix).

And here is the [product documentation](https://console.ng.bluemix.net/docs/manageapps/eclipsetools/eclipsetools.html) for your reference.